# Get elevation from multiband GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, elevation

I got this multi-band GeoTIFF from a government agency explicitly mentioning it referred to elevation in meters. But how do I combine the values of each band pixel into the elevation?

What's the function `elevation(band1(x,y),band2(x,y),band3(x,y))`? Is there any standard?

```
$ gdalinfo hipsometria.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: hipsometria.tif
Size is 5803, 11563
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / Portugal TM06",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["Portugual TM06",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",39.6682583333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-8.13310833333333,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Topographic mapping (medium scale)."],
        AREA["Portugal - mainland - onshore."],
        BBOX[36.95,-9.56,42.16,-6.19]],
    ID["EPSG",3763]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-128025.000000000000000,276125.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (50.000000000000000,-50.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -128025.000,  276125.000) (  9d40'54.62"W, 42d 8'39.29"N)
Lower Left  ( -128025.000, -302025.000) (  9d34'12.75"W, 36d56'19.23"N)
Upper Right (  162125.000,  276125.000) (  6d10'19.47"W, 42d 8'16.58"N)
Lower Right (  162125.000, -302025.000) (  6d18'48.20"W, 36d56' 0.34"N)
Center      (   17050.000,  -12950.000) (  7d56' 5.05"W, 39d33' 5.22"N)
Band 1 Block=5803x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=5803x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=5803x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

The directory still has another file `hiposmetria.tfw` :

```
50.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
0.00000000000000
-50.00000000000000
-128000.00000000000000
276100.00000000000000
[tkImageCom]
ImageFile D:\Prj\MDT_50M\mdt50\hdr.bmp
```

I realized as well that just Red and Green bands have values, Blue is set to zero

Comment: Are there any other files in the directory that stores your TIFF?

Comment: @GBG just a `.tfw` with no more relevant data

Comment: @GBG they also mention the scale is `1:50000` but I still don't get how does it map, nor even if this scale is related to altitude

Comment: Don't they provide metadata about their dataset?
One possible method is described in question gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245562/…